# Bar Chart not scaling to size of BarChartView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller, ios-charts

I am using the [ios-charts](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts) library by Daniel Gindi to try and create a bar chart.

I programatically create a BarChartView with a red background, and fill it with hard-coded data. The view is sized correctly, however the bar chart doesn't scale properly and is cut off when it reaches the top of the view.

**My view looks like this**:

[image]

This view controller is instantiated inside a scrollview using the storyboard method `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier`. However when I make this view controller the initial view controller, the chart scales correctly, and looks like this:

[image]

**Why does my chart scale incorrectly?**

I would also like to note that if I set the `leftAxis.axisMaxValue` property of the incorrectly-scaled graph to something large, like 100, the graph looks like this:

[image]

I will also provide the code I used to create the graph, minus the 30+ lines I used to set properties and the data of the graph.

```
override func viewDidLoad(){
    var chart : UIView?
    let gBFrame = self.graphBackground.frame
    let frame = CGRect(origin: gBFrame.origin, size: CGSize(width: gBFrame.width, height: gBFrame.height-25))
    chart = BarChartView(frame: frame)
    self.view.addSubview(chart!)
    constrainChart()
}

func constrainChart(){

    if type == "Bar Chart"{            
        chart!.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        let leftConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.chart!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Left, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.graphBackground, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Left, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        let rightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.chart!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Right, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.graphBackground, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Right, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        let topConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.chart!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.graphBackground, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        let bottomConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.chart!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.graphBackground, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: -25)
        self.view.addConstraints([leftConstraint,rightConstraint,topConstraint,bottomConstraint])
    } else if type == "Horizontal Bar Chart"{
    } else if type == "Pie Chart"{
    } else {

    }
    chart?.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

I can provide any additional information if it is helpful.

Any ideas on what could be the problem? Or what to try next?

**EDIT:**

when I instantiate the view controller inside the scrollview, I use NSLayoutConstraints to position it such that its left boundary is `2*self.view.frame.width` from the left boundary of the scrollview.

I find that if I set that constraint to 0, such that the view controller with the chart appears in the leftmost frame of the scrollview, the chart appears correctly. However if I change that constraint at all (like by one unit), the chart scales incorrectly again.

Right after I instantiate the view controller using the aforementioned storyboard method, I position it using the method whose code is shown below:

```
func setUpQuestionFrame(newViewController: UIViewController){

    var frame = newViewController.view.frame
    frame.origin.x = self.view.frame.size.width*2
    newViewController.view.frame = frame

    self.addChildViewController(newViewController)
    self.scrollView.addSubview(newViewController.view)
    newViewController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

    newViewController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    let widthConstraintVCBAR = NSLayoutConstraint(item: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: newViewController.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    view.addConstraint(widthConstraintVCBAR)

    let heightConstraintVCBAR = NSLayoutConstraint(item: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: newViewController.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    view.addConstraint(heightConstraintVCBAR)

    let horizontalConstraintVCBAR = NSLayoutConstraint(item: newViewController.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Left, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: scrollView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Right, multiplier: 1, constant: 5)//self.view.frame.width*2)
    view.addConstraint(horizontalConstraintVCBAR)

    let verticalConstraintVCBAR = NSLayoutConstraint(item:  newViewController.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: scrollView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    view.addConstraint(verticalConstraintVCBAR)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was solved by adding `chart!.notifyDataSetChanged()`, which tells the chart to reconfigure once it receives new data.

It was the same solution that was used in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36814192/how-to-constrain-ios-chart-to-size-of-view/36960536#36960536) question.